# Rounded corners on a Webpart will not display

Tags: css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, rounded-corners

After having researched how to add rounded corners to a webpart, I settled on using this method -

http://corriehaffly.wordpress.com/2011/03/10/adding-rounded-corners-to-web-part-header-for-sharepoint-2010/

However, it refuses to work. For some reason, when trying to apply the CSS to ms-wpTdSpace it isn't displaying the rounded corners. However the modification of the background of .ms-WPHeader is working fine.

I've tried using !important, or setting a higher z-index but nothing so far, here is what is in my CSS being loaded.

```
.ms-WPHeader td { background: url('../images/bg-bar.png') repeat-x; border-bottom: none !important;}
.ms-WPHeader td.ms-wpTdSpace { background: url('../images/bg-barcorners.png') top right !important;}
.ms-WPHeader td:first-child.ms-wpTdSpace { background-position: top left !important; }
```

---

After trying the solution below, and moving on to try several other different types of CSS to perform the same action I get nothing. The CSS is successfully changing the title bar using the bg-bar image, but when it comes to the corners they do not want to display.

I am viewing the page in IE 9, Chrome, and Moz4.0.1

Comment: I've merged your unregistered account into your registered account. You can now edit your question, leave comments under answers you receive and eventually accept the answer that helps you the most.

Comment: After trying the solution below, and moving on to try several other different types of CSS to perform the same action I get nothing. The CSS is successfully changing the title bar using the bg-bar image, but when it comes to the corners they do not want to display.

Comment: That should (probably) become a part of your question. Hint: click the `edit` link, or leave a comment under the answer (hint: the `add comment` link underneath it)

Comment: Thank you, I have followed your instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a space after `.ms-WPHeader td:first-child`

to read

```
.ms-WPHeader td:first-child .ms-wpTdSpace { background-position: top left !important; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but even after making this change it did not fix my problem. I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: It should definitely be without space, so .ms-WPHeader td:first-child.ms-wpTdSpace